# Stack with mode in O(1)

Tags: statistics, stack

Is there any way that I can keep track of the stack and get is Mode in O(1) time?

I know I have tried to implement a Min or Max Stack. But this one is a new for me. Any thoughts??

Comment: Sounds like you'll also need a hash-table to map values to counts.

Comment: yeah I can do that but that will increase the space complexity? and furthermore how am I to fetch the key with max value in O(1)? I'll have to scan through the whole entryset of the MAP?

Comment: You'd combine it with the same trick used for the min/max-stack.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is the same as a min-stack or max-stack, just that now we have to keep track of the count of elements in the stack so we can decide if a newly-pushed element changed the mode.  (You can generalize this to any operation where you can provide a (possibly stateful) function `(currentValue, beingPushed) -> nextValue` and guarantee that popping returns to the previous value.)

```
public class ModeStack<T> {
    private final Deque<T> stack = new ArrayDeque<>(), modeStack = new ArrayDeque<>();
    private final Map<T, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();
    public ModeStack() {}
    public void push(T t) {
        stack.push(t);
        int tCount = count.getOrDefault(t, 0)+1;
        count.put(t, tCount);
        if (modeStack.isEmpty())
            modeStack.push(t);
        else
            modeStack.push(tCount > count.get(modeStack.peek())
                    ? t : modeStack.peek());
    }
    //throws NoSuchElementException if stack is empty
    public T pop() {
        int newCount = count.get(stack.peek())-1;
        //remove unneeded map entries to prevent memory retention
        if (newCount == 0)
            count.remove(stack.peek());
        else
            count.put(stack.peek(), newCount);
        modeStack.pop();
        return stack.pop();
    }
    //returns null if stack is empty; ties broken by earliest-value-first
    public T mode() {
        return modeStack.peek();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ModeStack<Integer> s = new ModeStack<>();
        s.push(1);
        System.out.println(s.mode());
        s.push(2);
        s.push(2);
        System.out.println(s.mode());
        s.pop();
        System.out.println(s.mode());
    }
}
```

Maintaining the map does not change the asymptotic space complexity, as in the worst case all keys map to 1 and the map has size `n` -- but the element stack and mode stack are also size `n`, so the total space usage is `O(n)`.